# How to center text between page and not divs?

Tags: html, css

So I want to center some text (a `p` element) on the page but I have a `div` floating to the left and this affects the text alignment to center around the `div` instead of the page. How can I fix this?

Also please go fullscreen to see what I'm talking about.

```css
#img1 {
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
}

#box1 {
  width: max-width;
  height: 1650px;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

#box2 {
float:left;
padding-left:250px;
}

#box3 {
text-align:center;
}

#p1 {
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
<div id="box2">
<img id="img1" src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="box3"
<p id="p1">
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum lorum ipsum<br>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo: `<div id="box3"` missing a `>`

Comment: Do you want the text to be on top of the image, or below it??

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in the code but it works the way i intended for demonstration purposes anyway. Also i already got the answer below but i wanted it to be side by side like the code snippet, just centered horizontally on the page instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this on box#2

`position:absolute;`

Also, remove the `text-align: left` on `#p1`

This way, your text will be centered on the whole page even with that box floating on the left.